# Setting private property via reflection - property not being found

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, system.reflection

TLDR: Can't set a private field on an instance of [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Batch/TransactionalBatchResponse.cs) class using reflection, despite having the correct binding flags.

I'm working on a C# unit test to verify batch update functionality on a database, specifically Azure Cosmos using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos NuGet v3.32.0.
In the actual logic to batch update, I create a [TransactionalBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.transactionalbatch?view=azure-dotnet) and add individual operations to that batch synchronously, then run the entire batch as an async transaction, like so:

```
var batch = _container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey(values.FirstOrDefault().PartitionKey)); 

foreach (var element in values) 
{ 
   batch.ReplaceItem(element.Id, element);            
}
var response = await batch.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
var individualResults = response.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

In order to test this, I planned to use Moq to setup CreateTransactionalBatch to return a TransactionalBatch of my own creation, but it starts to get a bit hairy there. The TransactionalBatch class does not have a public constructor, and the results field that is enumerated to get individual operation results is private. [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Batch/TransactionalBatchResponse.cs) is the actual class definition.

My first thought was to use reflection to set the desired results on the TransactionalBatchResponse, so I'm using pretty standard reflection logic to do that:

```
 public static void SetPrivatePropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propName, T val)
 {
     Type t = obj.GetType();
     t.InvokeMember(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, obj, new object[] { val });
}
```

On a batch response that I attempted to create this way (not great, I know, but there's no parameterless ctor for an activator):

`var response = RuntimeHelpers.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(TransactionalBatchResponse)) as TransactionalBatchResponse;`

Which ends up looking like this:

```
var response = RuntimeHelpers.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(TransactionalBatchResponse)) as TransactionalBatchResponse;
ReflectionExtensions.SetPrivatePropertyValue(response, "results", individualResults);
```

When I try it, my method throws an error:
System.MissingMethodException : Method 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.TransactionalBatchResponse.results' not found.

when there's clearly a results field defined in the TransactionalBatchResponse class, and I've set BindingFlags.Instance and BindingFlags.NonPublic on the reflection method.

Is this expected behavior related to the object being uninitialized or am I missing something else? I would assume that since the field is defined in the class, it should still work?

I also am aware that having to do this is probably indicative of a code smell, and I'm most likely going to just isolate and wrap some of the logic somewhere else to make it more testable, but I'm curious why this behavior might be happening in this particular case.

Comment: Is `results` a *property* or a *field*?

Comment: I'd say a field by definition. Is there actually a distinction as far as reflection is concerned?

Comment: Yes of course, field != property. Please show the class definition

Comment: The class definition is in the question, if you mean for the transactionbatchresult class. I think you guys answered my question though, after some quick reading on reflection methods. I'll come back in a bit with a working solution in case anyone else confused the two in this context.

Comment: Given that the `BindingFlags` enumeration has `SetField` and `SetProperty` values, it should be clear that fields and properties are treated differently. I'm guessing that that flag is the only change you'd need to make.